# Java application closed but still the dist process running

Tags: java, swing, process

I have created a java application on netbeans 7 .Now By using netbeans ihave created the jar file of application.And when am clicking it application start running.But the if i closed the application the application processed killed,but still the dist child process is running though all window closed.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. The process ends when you close your application. What do you mean with _but still the dist application running?_

Comment: What do you mean by "the dist process"?  Are you referring to some specific external application called `dist`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a variable(FileReader,...) open, remember that you need to close them close()

if its a gui application call JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: Wow.. I hope not many animals were sacrificed for the [haruspication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haruspex) required to infer that answer!  +1

Comment: @AndrewThompson how do you mean? is this a bad anwser?

Comment: *"is this a bad anwser?"* It is a brilliant answer.  I was amazed how you guessed (short of using using black magic) the answer from the lack of information.  :)

Comment: Haha, oke, thanks, I made that mistake alot,so it was just a guess :p

Comment: Ahh.. The 'been there, done that, got the fix' route to answering questions.  A lot of my answers are inspired from the same types of experiences.

Comment: @Arno you should totally buy a lottery ticket today ;)

Comment: Haha, i can't i'm not old enough :p e